# rss feed google media:group

Tags: javascript, api, rss

My problem is the following: I wrote a rss.xml with a

```
<media:group>
  <media:thumbnail url:"johndoe.at/images/test.jpg" width='auto' height='50'>
  ....
  ....
```

for a picture.

It is possible to get everything out of the rss but the media thing can't be extracted. How can I do this? All other fields I extract with the following JS code:

```
function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://fastpshb.appspot.com/feed/1/fastpshb");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var title   = entry.title;
        var content = entry.content;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be available as a mediaGroups property array, so you would have

```
// verify mediaGroups are present and then retrieve the first one's URL.
if (entry.mediaGroups) {
   var thumbnail = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url;
}
```